# nginx proxy_pass wordpress on apache with Two separated server

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

I have a nginx server with domain name[www.sample.com] and IP adress [1.1.1.1].
Also I have an apache Server that contains WordPress with ip[2.2.2.2].

Nginx Configured to proxy_pass [www.sample.com/app](http://www.sample.com/app) to 2.2.2.2/ap.
WordPress loads paths, but could not load Css Resource on wordpress wp-include

Comment: what does the console show ? Inspect what is being shown when css resources are requested. preserve logs and note if the resources are redirected to some other location. We can debug only if we can come into conclusion whether it is css errror, or redirection failiure, sslfailiure or perhaps file permission error.

Comment: message on console is Loading failed for the <script> with source and http response is 404.

Comment: you can use ip(2.2.2.2) only and try to load the actual apache-wordpress installation. And note if you got any issues with the server. For me this seems to be a file permissions error that is being thrown.  This article can help you in the process https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/.
To summarize, check if it is an issue with actual apache-wordpress linkage, then move on to troubleshoot nginx config if any.

Comment: I need to wrap apache server and wordpress behind of nginx server. checked again all permissions and every things were correct.

Comment: i have recommended you to inspect WordPress over apache first, if it works all fine, then you can move on to nginx and resolve any redirection failures. It is important that you fragment your issue, and identify where the problem area is. Especially, in your case  where you are unsure if its the wordpress issue or nginx issue.

Comment: i solved, it. I set this line (2.2.2.2 www.sample.com) in /etc/hosts on WordPress server.

Comment: good to know, you can try answering your own question in detail then.